# android.support.v5.app.Fragment or android.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

im using Android Studio 1.0 Rc1.

I have created a MainActivity (TabbedActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

it imports:

```
...
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
```

so heres the problem:
Ive made another FragmentActivity:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
```

this on imports:

now i want to do this:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return ScoutLogFragment.newInstance("a","b");
        case 1:
            return  BlankFragment.newInstance("a", "b");
        case 2:
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        default:
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

    }

}
```

but it tells me:

> "Required: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
>      Found   : de.example.local.scouttools.BlankFragment"

if i change my Main activity import to android.app.Fragment; t tells me that the return type of my  getItem(int position) is wrong.

I dont get why one imports android.app.Fragment and the other android.support.app.v4.Fragment,
How to fix that?

Comment: Did you try to change import manually?

Answer (score 2):

It always depends which devices runs your Fragments.

Support V4 is used with the support library.

It can be imported in the build.gradle with

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

If you dont use the Support library only devices with Android 3.0 or newer may use your fragments.

If you use the Support library all devices with at least 2.1 can use your Fragments.

Take care: If you use the support library your app will be a little big bigger in filesize.

Make sure that you import the proper Fragment Class for the Support library. It is

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

If you device to impor the ActionBar you will also need the Support library v7.

The Import is

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

The Required library can be imported by gradle with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

Oh, and your BlankFragment seems to import the wrong classes. Validate that it uses the v4 Fragment in the BlankFragment class aswell.

Comment: ok ill try that. But i still dont get it why he imports the support library in my MainActivity by default, while he imports android.app.Fragment on my BlankFragment :s

Comment: Because Intellij does not analyze the other sources. Each file generates it's own sources. Usually you should get a prompt to decide which Fragment Class you want to import.

Comment: ok so ive just changed my th import to android.support.v4.Fragment(at the BlankFragment) and now it works... now ive made antoher Fragtment(listFragment) and it also imports the android.app.Fragment.. do i need to change it manually to android.support.v4.Fragment on every single Fragment i will make in future? :O

Comment: Yes and no. Usually you should be prompted to include the proper Fragment Class if there are two Classes matching the same name. It seems that you have enabled "Auto Import". Go to File->Settings->Editor->Auto Import and enable "Show Import Popup". You should also change Insert Imports on Paste to Ask and disable Add unambiguous imports on the fly.